# .NET Framework v1 and resources

Tags: .net, resources

I have a problem, I need to add raw file resource to the .NET Framework v1.0 application, but I can't find any information of how to do it (is it even possible for this oldie?). YES that must be for .NET Framework 1.0. Also how to read those resources, global::namespace.resources.NameOfTheResource seems to be not implemented in this .NET Framework. Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `ResssourceManager` class.

```
    ResourceManager resourceManager = new ResourceManager ("MyCompany.MyProject.SomeResources", GetType ().Assembly);

    Bitmap image = (Bitmap)resourceManager.GetObject ("MyBitmapName");
```

Link : http://www.jelovic.com/articles/resources_in_visual_studio.htm

Comment: But did you see how you need to add resources for .NET Framework v1.0 appliction in Visual Studio 2003? It's pretty weird, I can't import any files to the resource file (like it's done for .NET v2.0 apps), I can't figure it out?

Comment: sorry, saw that link and im trying it now :0